# Error: Not implemented: HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is how my test case looks :

```
const renderCard = ({
  onSubmit = jest.fn(),
}: RenderCardParams = {}) => {
  return render(
        <Card title={title} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
        </Card>,
  );
}; 

it("should invoke onSubmit when form is submitted", async () => {
      const onSubmit = jest.fn();
      window.HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = () => {};
      const { getByText } = renderCard({ onSubmit });
      const button = getByText("Save").closest("button");
      if (button) {
        fireEvent.click(button);
      }
      await wait(() => expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled());
 });
```

I am receiving "Error: Not implemented: HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit". I tried the solution mentioned here https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1937 , but it did not work. I do not want to silence the errors but implement the test correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 51):

I had a similar issue which was resolved by calling the `event.preventDefault()` method.

This would need to be called in your 'onSubmit' function i think

```
const onSubmit = jest.fn(e => e.preventDefault());
```

edit: woops forgot to invoke it!

Comment: For me this worked ```submit = jest.fn().mockImplementation((e) => e.preventDefault());```

Comment: Side note: I came across this error when I used an onClick instead on onSubmit on a form

Comment: Can you explain (1) What's happening (error case) and (2) why `e.preventDefault` helps?

Comment: Adding the call to `preventDefault` on form submits is a very good idea in react, as the default browser behavior for the form is to reload the page. We rarely want that to happen in react.

Answer (score 9):

I had to mock the implementation of my `onSubmit` function to clear the error, preventing the default submit behavior.

Give something like this a try:

```js
const onSubmit = jest.fn();


it("should invoke onSubmit when form is submitted", async () => {
      onSubmit.mockImplementation(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
      });

      const { getByText } = renderCard({ onSubmit });
      const button = getByText("Save").closest("button");
      if (button) {
        fireEvent.click(button);
      }
      await wait(() => expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled());
 });
```

You can read more about event.preventDefault in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault).

Something else that worked for me was using RTL's `fireEvent.submit`, although you need to get a form element for that to work. Assuming your implementation of `Card` renders a form in a way that's recognizable by `getByRole`, you could also try something like this:

```js
fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole('form'));
```

That would be in lieu of simulating the button click, which may be acceptable in your case since you seem to be testing form submission rather than the button's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I had also a similar issue. 
However, for me this was happening because I was using `userEvent.click` and the solution of placing `preventDefault()` in the `fn` didn't work for me since the click event and submit event are different.

I had to switch to `fireEvent.submit` and that worked without the need to prevent default and be able to test the form submission.

PS: I was using a `form` to wrap the inputs

Error

```js
   import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
```

Work

```js
   import {fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
```

This is the basic form implentation

```js
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <input type={'text'} placeholder={'user name'} value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
     <br/>
     <input type={'text'} placeholder={'password'} value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
     <br/>
     <input type={'submit'} disabled={!username && !password} value={'Login'} />
   </form>
```

And here you can see the implementation of the test to handle the submitted event

```js
it('should handle submit event', async () => {
    const handleSubmitFn = jest.fn();
    render(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmitFn}/>);

    const username = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/user name/);
    const password= screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/);
    const submitButton = screen.getByText(/login/i);

    userEvent.type(username, 'myuserbla');
    userEvent.type(password, 'mypwd');

    fireEvent.submit(submitButton)

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(handleSubmitFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `type="button"` to the button element is also effective. This will dismiss that error.

Realised this because I had a save and cancel button. I tested the save first and this error didn't occur but when I tested the cancel the error occurred.

When I came to this answer, reading the first answer gave me a clue and as I was about to add the `event.preventDefault()` I realised `type="button"` was missing on the cancel button.

Both buttons are child elements of the form.

Comment: This kept my enter button from submitting a form, however.

Comment: The button to submit the form _should_ be a `type="submit"`, and the submit event of the form should be handled. Changing the type alters the semantics of the form. As @Brent writes, the browser by default submit the form when you press enter. Changing the type also affects how screen readers and other assistive technologies can interact with the form.